# Import table with irregular linebreaks

Tags: r, data.table

I have a 2.8gb text file that I'm trying to import into R.

1) I used `fread(file='file.txt',sep = ';',header = T,nrows = 1000,stringsAsFactors = F,fill=T)` to take a quick look, and I saw that some rows happen to show some columns with NA's and in the row below are the values that should be in the NA's place.

2) Next, I used HJSplit to see a part of the file in a notepad and noticed that there are linebreaks in the middle of some rows, making these rows occupy two rows. Here's an ilustration of what's happening (example of ';' separated file with 4 columns):

```
id;name;age;sex  
150;bob;40;F  
151;luke;20;M  
152;mary  
20;F  
153;larry;30;M
```

Question: Is there a way that I can solve this problem?

One thing that came to my mind was to use the fact that the number of columns are defined, but I don't know how.

Comment: Whoever prepared that file messed up big time. Your best shot is to get properly formatted data: maybe it is out there and you can ask for it? Otherwise you might be able to use some heuristics to reconstruct the data: a field containing the single letter `F` or `M` was probably a `sex` column; `id` that are non-consecutive are probably ages; and so on...

Comment: Yes, you could write a function that adds an index of row positions, compares it with the content of the "id" variable, decides if they match, and if they dont, complete the current line with the elements of the second line. 
Yet, if If all the observation follows a strict rule of having 4 variablesseparated by a semicolon, you could apply regex to correct the misplaced carriage return.
It most probably would be faster to fix the txt outside R. Run a regex formula were all carriage return not preceded by 3 semicolons should be discarded.

Comment: which program can I use to do this regex approach?

Comment: You can try `awk` or `sed` at the command line, they are available for both Windows and Linux.